# Socket.IO - io is not defined (fails on different domain)

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I know this error message has been asked in lots of question but I haven't found one that matches my situation. Below I show you the server (node.js) and the client code. The socket.io.js file is included and definitely present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs if you are not listening to the correct port.

**Server**

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

**Client**

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

If the server and the client is not listening to the same port, then you will not be able to load the socket.io library and io will be undefined. I'm guessing that you did not specify the port on the client when connecting to a different domain. If you are using express, the port number should be the port Express listens to by default.